# iphone - notification not being fired

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Goal:

I want to use the Observer Pattern so that when one uiimageview receives a different background image, then 2 other uiimageviews will listen for that change, and then change themselves.

Strategy:

Based on what I read about observer pattern in objective-c, I decided to implement the nsnotificationcenter.

Code:

self refers to the RemoteViewManagerController, updateButtons is the method that will be called when the ImageSwap event is fired, and object refers to the "main" uiimageview, that is, the uiimageview that when changed will cause changes in other uiimageviews.

```
- (void)registerButtonObserver:(UIView *)currentView
{  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateButtons:) name:@"ImageSwap" object:[self.view viewWithTag:1]];
}
```

setDefaultButtons is invoked, and we iterate through the buttons and target buttons based on tag. The "main" uiviewimage has a tag of 1. So we call setImageChange to change the background  image of that button, and as a result, I want to fire the ImageSwap event, to change the other two uiimageview buttons, and I pass in those buttons part of the userinfo dictionary. The idea is when updateButtons is invoked, I can reference those buttons in the userinfo dictionary.

```
- (void)setDefaultButtons:(UIView *)currentView
{
    for( UIView *view in currentView.subviews ) {  
        if( [view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] ) {  
            if( view.tag == 1 ){                
                [self setImageChange:@"fence" forButton:view];

                NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"subview1", @"subview2", nil];
                NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.view viewWithTag:4], [self.view viewWithTag:5], nil];
                NSDictionary *items = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects 
                                                                       forKeys:keys];
                NSLog(@"But we sure to get here right");
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"ImageSwap" object:view userInfo:items];                
            }
            else if(view.tag == 2){
                [self setImageChange:@"siren" forButton:view];
            }
            else if(view.tag == 3){
                [self setImageChange:@"auxiliary" forButton:view];
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Note that I know that we get to the postNotificationName line, because this line does fire: NSLog(@"But we sure to get here right");

I don't get any errors. But this line in RemoteViewManagerController.m:

```
- (void)updateButtons:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
    NSLog(@"Do we get here?");
}
```

is never called.

Comment: Why aren't you just calling the image change functions when you change the background image? I'm not sure that you need a notification center.

Comment: Are you updating image views across classes? If not then I would not use the observer pattern. The observer pattern is used to send global updates and shouldn't be used if these changes are all being made inside the same class. 

You can run into a lot of problems with observers if they are not handled properly. Such as trying to add an existing one or removing one that isn't there. 

I would suggest that if this is all this is being handled in the same class to just use logic to determine when to update the respective image views.

Comment: So how would the code above cause problems?

Comment: @cory can you explain  how would the code above cause problems?

Comment: Answered below by Caleb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when two subviews have the same tag, `-viewWithTag:` just returns the first one that it finds. So if there happen to be two views with tag=1, it's quite possible that you're observing the wrong one. Try changing the `object` parameter in you `-addObserver...` call to `nil`, which will indicate that you want to observe that notification for all objects.

Comment: I just mean to do it as a test -- it'd be an easy way to figure out whether you're observing the wrong object.

Comment: So you say that the object param indicates that I want to observe the notification for all objects when set to nil, but I thought the addObserver param is what was determining who will be observing and in this case it was set to self.

Comment: The object doing the observing is `self`. The object that `self` is observing is `[self.view viewWithTag:1]`. What I'm saying above is that `[self.view viewWithTag:1]` may not be the view that you think it is -- if some other view in the view hierarchy also has tag=1, you may be observing that view instead of the one you have in mind. Substituting `nil` for `[self.view viewWithTag:1]` in your `-addObserver:...` call will cause your `updateButton:` method to be called whenever *any* object posts a notification named "ImageSwap".